# $A$ and $B$, $5\times 5$ matrices having common eigenvectors. If the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(x-1)^2$ and $B$ is nilpotent then $B^3=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> [True/False] Let $A$ and $B$ be $5\times 5$ matrices such that $A$ and
>   $B$ have common eigen vectors. If the minimal polynomial of $A$ is
>   $(x-1)^2$ and $B$ is nilpotent then $B^3=0$

Any hints on how can I approach this problem?

Since minimal polynomial of A has only $1$ as a root, it means all the eigenvalues of A are $1$. I am not able to deduce much from other information given.

I feel that statement is True but I am not able to show why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Jordan canonical form of $A$ can only have blocks of the form $\pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 0 & 1\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{1}$.  The only possibilities are one block of the first type and three of the second, or two of the first and one of the second.  In the first case there are four linearly independent eigenvectors, and in the second there are three.  Thus $B$ has either four or three linearly independent eigenvectors (for eigenvalue $0$).  Its Jordan canonical form can't have a block bigger than $3 \times 3$.  Of course since $B$ is nilpotent, all its eigenvalues are $0$.  Thus $B^3 = 0$.

Comment: I am not able to understand why JCF of B can't have block bigger than $3\times 3$. Rest is clear. Thanks.

Comment: Because a block has only one linearly independent eigenvector.  If it had a $4 \times 4$ block, that leaves room for only one other block ($1 \times 1)$, and thus only two linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Have a good day.